# If I'm using SQLAlchemy-migrations, how do I get the final, full schema in 1 file?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema, sqlalchemy

I'm new at SQLAlchemy and migrations.  Basically, what I understand it this:

- Create base models.py, with basic structure of tables.
- When I expand my tables/columns, I create a 'migration script' (with upgrade/downgrade)
- I keep doing this, and I keep creating these scripts

Pretty soon, I'll have like 50 scripts...right?

But I still want 1 file that defines the schema. So I can look at the file and know my own schema.  Right now, if I open models.py, I'll see the basic structure that I built a long time ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably several solutions, but one way of doing it is to keep the "model" quite separate from the migrations.

Keep the model up to date.  Edit this freely during development to get the desired functionality.  But before you do start editing it, first *make a copy* and put it aside (astute readers probably call this source control).

Once you are homing in on the final version of the new feature you're implementing, and you have a good idea of what features you'll need to add to your migration script, open the older version of the model and trim it down to just the tables you are trying to modify.  Include the pared down models in the migration script itself.

Another option is to rely heavily on table reflection in the main models module.  The migration scripts don't interact with that at all, instead they fully describe the tables they are migrating within each script.  This has the advantage of making the models (mostly) work well on any schema version you might be on.  The downside is that full schema reflection will slow application startup, sometimes significantly.